# I'm getting ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/items" even though Routes look correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm new to programming and have been learning Ruby on rails for about 11 weeks.

When running a feature spec (using RSpec and Capybara) on a simple "To do" list app. I get this error:

```
Failures:

  1) User creates ITEM Successfully
     Failure/Error: click_button 'Save'
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/items"
```

Here is my routes file:

```
  devise_for :users


    resources :items, only: [:new, :create, :show] 


  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'
  root to: "welcome#index"

end
```

...here is the "items" controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    @item.save
    redirect_to @item
  end


   private

   def item_params
     params.require(:item).permit(:body)
   end
 end
```

the item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list

  scope :unfinished, -> { where('done' => false) }
  scope :unfinished_and_recent, -> { unfinished.where("created_at > ?", Time.now-7.days) }
  scope :finished, -> { where('done' => true) }

  validates :body, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
  validates :list, presence: true
 end
```

the spec:

```
require 'rails_helper' 

feature 'User creates ITEM' do
  scenario 'Successfully' do
    visit new_item_path
    fill_in 'Body', with: 'washcar'
    click_button 'Save' 
  end  
end
```

and the item factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :item do 
    body 'itembody'
    list 
    end
 end
```

...and here is the form:

```
<h1>Items#new</h1>

<%= form_for Item.new do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :body, placeholder: 'Body' %> 
   <%= form.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

i ran rake routes:

```
   items POST   /items(.:format)                  items#create
new_item GET    /items/new(.:format)              items#new
    item GET    /items/:id(.:format)              items#show
   about GET    /about(.:format)                  welcome#about
```

Comment: Could you provide the form you are submiting?

Comment: Ok - just added the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
resources :items, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index]
```

If you run `rake routes` at the command line, it should show you the routes available for your app (and help explain the above).

Also, in case you haven't already read it:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: After running rake routes, I get : root GET    /

Comment: Did you already add the index action to the items resources route (as above)?

Comment: Yes. I ran rake routes, and posted them.

Comment: Nah, I mean did you modify `routes.rb` to incorporate the line I listed above? The request from the error you posted--"[GET] "/items"" indicates that Rails is looking for an index method on Items, but the existing resources route only includes :new, :create, and :show methods. Try adding :index (if you haven't already--I couldn't tell from your response).

Comment: That did it, but I'm not sure why. since i had not defined an index method in my items controller. I added :index to routes like you said, then of course had to add the index method to the controller, and then I had to create the view. After that, the spec passed.

Comment: Why did Rails require that a route that did not exist yet (index) be matched with a controller method that didn't exist?

Comment: Did you read the routing guide? (That's not meant to be snarky--just that the guides are pretty good at explaining some of the fundamental Rails concepts, probably better than can be done in this space.) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: EricLowber, I believe your `@item.save` is failing because you just add a body and do not assign it to a list, and then when you try to redirect to it, because it's not persisted, it redirects to index, and as you don't have the index it throws the error. There's don't need to have an index action, you just need to handle the item properly.